# Eloquent Relationship without Pivot Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have **3** tables:

1. **`customer`**: `fields: id, name`
2. **`item`**: `fields: id, name`
3. **`customer_items`**: `fields: customer_id, item_id, qty`

`Customer` and `Item` have their separate Models as we would expect.

**Question: How would I relate these two(Customer and Item) without having a pivot model.**

*I want to directly get customer items using `$customer->items` instead of doing `$customer->customerItem->items` which I find unnecessary since I don't want to track customerItems & customer by item.*

*Also, I cannot directly use `customer_items` table for `Item` model as I might need to retrieve all items in its controller.*

Comment: "_instead of doing $customer->customerItem->items_" How are your model relations set up?

Comment: @kerbholz that's the question, how would I set it up that Customer can have hasMany relation with Items without having a pivot model for CustomerItems. *given there's a pivot table to refer to*

Comment: on customer model, setup relation hasMany to customer_items model

Comment: No, I meant, how are your models related in your code right now?! https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many What you want is "standard" behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @kerbholz (but they didn't create an answer so here it is), in your customer model you need the following function:

```php
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item');
    }
```

Which assumes your Item model class sits within `App`.  You may also do the reverse in your Item model.

Now you should be able to do `$customer->items` and get a collection of items. 
If you want to include the `qty` field then you need:

```php
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item')->withPivot('qty');
    }
```

Note that you still need the pivot table, you can't escape that, but you can now navigate it in a more elegant manner.

Comment: Since Item model's table is `item`, how would it know that it gets the relationship from the pivot table? What if I name it in a different manner like `customer_____items_collection`.

Comment: For it to work within the Laravel framework, and have laravel magically take care of it, you must conform to the naming convention.  Which is alphabetic in order modelA_modelB for the pivot table name

Comment: thanks man! finally made sense. btw, you may specify the pivot table by passing 2nd argument to belongsToMany.. `belongsToMany('App\Item', 'customer_____items_collection')` *it was so confusing, why would laravel use belongsToMany instead of hasMany, hasMany would make much more sense*

Answer (score 0):

creat `customer_items` table and include `custmer_item_id` and `user_id` . in `User` model include this function

```
public function basket() // example
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'customer_items', 'user_id', 'custmer_item_id');
    }
```